# xamarin Android Visual Studio Slow debugging

Tags: xamarin

Have just started trial of Xamarin using the supplied Task solution (android).  Stepping through code is slow.  Is this because of the emulator or Xamarin in general?  Do people debug using real devices?

Many Thanks

Neil

Comment: this is the android emulator, it is super slow, on windows as on osx

Comment: Even on the device it is pretty slow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The emulator is very slow in general.

For a better experience, do try using the Intel Emulators - http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/configuring_the_x86_emulator - but these are still not as good as a real device.

Answer (score 2):

As of May 2015, debugging Xamarin Android applications on an emulator is no longer slow - in fact it is very comparable to a real device if using the right tool and configuring it properly.

- The [Xamarin Android Player](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-player/) provides a virtual machine image to run in VirtualBox that is super-fast.
- [Intel is providing special images](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/accelerating_android_emulators/) to run the emulator with special images and when turning on "Use host GPU" it runs pretty fast.

[image: Xamarin Android Player in action (left). Correctly configured Android Virtual Device that uses Intel Image and host GPU (right).]

The only difference that I realized is that the Xamarin Android Player is slightly faster, especially when deploying the app and attaching debugger (which makes is superior to the standard Emulator, which otherwise works fine too).

And by the way: you should definitely enable Fast Deployment in Visual Studio:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Speed is dependent on your development device performance. Debugging through real android device can provide you **much** faster steps through. Although if problem which I am solving isnt in UI layer (my projects often consists from two projects - UI and Work layer), I am using simple console application with reference on dll with work layer and simply unload project with UI.

Iam using Visual Studio 12 which screams that referenced .dll isnt fully supported but it works perfectly and super fast like in normal console application.

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using Xamarin Studio. In project settings you can find a way to build and deploy faster then you deploy to device, but **ONLY FOR DEBUG MODE**.

In **Xamarin Studio**,
 right-click you Android project and go to *Options*. There, inside *Build* group, go to *Android Build*. In *Packaging* tab, make sure you have both "*Use shared mono runtime*" and "*Fast assembly deployment*" checked. It builds for me in less than 8 seconds!!

It also works in **Visual Studio**:
right-click your Android project and go to *Properties*. In *Android Options* section, make sure you have "*Use shared mono runtime*" and "*Fast assembly deployment (debug mode only)*" checked. I've just tested my Solution and it seems to run as fast as in Xamarin studio.

As I mentioned, I actually use only Xamarin Studio and it's very fast. Obviously it will take much more time if it's you first deploy to a AVD (Android Virtual Device = emulator) since the shared mono runtime will also be deployed, but the consecutive ones will be lightning speed! :)

Remember also to use this fast deployment only for debugging, never for Release mode.
I've tested with an AVD running Android 2.3 and one running Android 4.0.3 and then both works as expected. This deployment configuration to AVD is faster than any device I've tested, but it only seems to work in emulator, not in my test devices. In my devices the app stops responding as soon as it opens.

Do not forget to comment here if it works fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I use all of my old devices and my current device for debugging. Its better for a number of reasons. One, the emulator is great, but you never know just how the app is going really look and feel until you test it on a device. Sometimes the emulator doesn't draw things exactly as they may appear on the real screen. Also, if you're using external applications provided by android like making calls, emailing you'll need a real device. However, all that being said, the emulator is a great place to start and get going. 
One tip is to never close the emulator once you get it running if you are doing a lot subsequent tests/bug fixes. That way you're emulator is already loaded in your computer's memory and doesn't have rebuild it each time.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using **Genymotion**: https://www.genymotion.com/

Or **Xamarin Android Player**: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/android-player/

They are faster and us some other have suggest select Use **Fast Deployment** on your settings